# Add a call to a shell command in XmlStarlet

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

I've read the best doc I found (is there any other better) on XmlStarlet (at http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) and did not find any way to call a shell command with an attribute as parameter.

I want the extraction from an XML file to give something along the lines:

```
attrib1 (full name of attrib1)
```

where what's in parentheses is the results of a shell command call, such as:

```
> get-full-name attrib1
full name of attrib1
```

Is there such a possibility from XmlStarlet?

Or do I have to play with special characters (chosen as markers) and a piped sed or awk command?

Any better idea?

Comment: I had started some experimental code to add a feature that could do this, but never finished it: https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/code/ci/xfun/log/

Comment: In which state is it?  Having a plan for it?  That's something really nice to have... Thx!

Comment: It's waiting for someone to give it some love ;)